# Find the inverse of the map $x \mapsto x^3+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I know the map is invertible and trying to show that $[x^3]_6=[x]_6$ but failed to do so.

Comment: You say "you know" the map is invertible, but then you ask how to show it...A map is invertible iff it is one-to-one and onto, i.e. iff it is bijective. Prove this...and drop the cumbersome notation: simply write $\;x\mapsto x^3+1\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z_6\;$ . It is enough to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to show that $[x^3]_6=[x]_6$:

- $[0^3]_6=[0]_6, [1^3]_6=[1]_6, [2^3]_6=[2]_6, [3^3]_6=[3]_6, [4^3]_6=[4]_6, [5^3]_6=[5]_6$
- $6|n^3-n=n(n^2-1)=n(n-1)(n+1),$ because the product of $2$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $2$ and the product of $3$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $3$

Therefore, you can invert the map $[x]_6\mapsto[x^3+1]_6=[x+1]_6$ by subtracting $[1]_6$.

Comment: another way:  by Fermat's little theorem, $3|n^3-n$ ; $n^2\equiv n$ so $n^3\equiv n^2\equiv n\pmod 2$; therefore $6|n^3-n$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$x^3+1=y^3+1\iff x^3=y^3\iff x=y\pmod 6$$

as you can check directly.

Since $\;\Bbb Z_6\;$ is a finite set, a map from it to itself is bijective iff it is injective...

The above check will wive that $\;y=x^3+1\implies x^3=y^3-1\implies x=\sqrt[3]{y^3-1}=y-1\;$ , and there you have your inverse map...Fill in details, now.